# Using beeline to run some sql on remote impala failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, beeline

when I useing this command got an error:

```
$ beeline --silent=true -u 'jdbc:hive2://[ip]:21050/[database];auth=noSasl' -n 'username' -p 'password' -e 'use [database]; create table test_table (id int, name string);'
```

> Error: AnalysisException: Could not resolve table reference: 'arcaccessdenied' (state=HY000,code=0)

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `impala-shell` is how you use Impala. You are simply connecting to HiveServer2

Comment: Note that you do not need a `USE` statement for the database you connect directly to in the `jdbc` string

Comment: Sure, we can use impala-shell, but we need to transfer to beeline.

Comment: beeline will run significantly slower than impala shell. You aren't using Impala at that point

Answer (score 0):

After test, I fixed this issue.

This is because I named the wrong table name.
"." dot is not allowed in the table name.

Right:

```
impala_test
```

Wrong:

```
impala_type.normal_test
```

Comment: You can have dots in table names, by the way. `SELECT * FROM \`my.table\``